# Replacement for Windows XP "View available wireless networks"

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

The title pretty much says it all. Does anyone know of a good replacement for windows XP's "View available wireless networks"?

I know of NetStumbler and the like, but I'd like something which can be integrated instead of Windows network manager.

Comment: Is this a laptop?

Comment: Uhmm, is what a laptop ? Yes, I'm using a laptop, why ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking the manufacturer's website of your laptop or wireless thingymebob.  Nearly all new laptops I handle come bundled with some form of wireless utility from the manufacturer of the wireless hardware or the laptop.  For example, the Intel hardware within a lot of the Dell Latitude models use [PROSet](http://www.intel.com/network/connectivity/products/wireless/proset/proset_software.htm).  Asus come with their own Wireless LAN Utility, Broadcom have their own utility, Buffalo has another, the list goes on.

I think it would be better to get one intended for your specific hardware than get something generic, if you don't want to use the built-in wireless zero configuration feature.

Comment: +1 @Kez The utility many vendors supply is excellent.    The latest I have for my ThinkPad is a big improvement and manages connections very well. Also does a pretty good site survey.